# How to exclude a specific pattern from regex in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a little trouble with a regular expression. I have the following one: `(A|C|G|T){3}` which gives every permutation of three letters from A,B,C,D but now I want to exclude three specific patterns: `"TAG"`, `"TAA"` and `"TGA"` . Tried with `[^]`, but it is not yielding expected results. Same goes using [look-around](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)(look ahead and look-behind).

What I am trying to achieve is to find all sub-strings who start with "ATG", end with either  "TAG", "TAA" or "TGA" and in the middle it should have triples of A,C,G or T.

Thanks for the help!

Here is what I have done so far:

```
(ATG)((((A|C|G|T)){3})[^TAG][^TAA][^TGA])*(TAG|TAA|TGA)

(ATG)((?!TAG)(?!TAA)(?!TGA)(((A|C|G|T)){3})*)(TAG|TAA|TGA)
```

Comment: Is this valid: `ATGCCTAGCTAA`? That is, are you looking for a number of triplets except some specific triplets or are you looking for a string of a length divisible by 3 where the exceptions are not substrings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

1) Start with ATG

2) A number of triplets, except 'TAG', 'TAA', and 'TGA'

3) One of the triplets 'TAG', 'TAA', or 'TGA'

This should work:

```
/
   (ATG)                       # Step 1
   ((?!TAG|TAA|TGA)[ACGT]{3})+ # Step 2
   (TAG|TAA|TGA)               # Step 3
/x
```

The difference from you second idea it to move the negative look-ahead inside the quantifier to get 'a number of triplet' step ensuring that neither of the triplets are one of the exceptions

This solution does not assume any commonality between the elements in step 2 and step 3. A simpler, but in your case equivalent, formulations would be:

1) Match 'ATG'

2) Match a number of triplets

3) ... until you match 'TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA'.

To do this you just need to make the quantifier in step 2 non-greedy, as this would test is Step 3 matches before trying if step 2 matched again.

Then the solution would look like:

```
/ (ATG) ([ACGT]{3})*? (TAG|TAA|TGA) /x
```

An alternative interpretation might be:

1) Start with ATG

2) A number of triplets

3) One of the triplets 'TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA'

4) The substring found in step 2 must not contain the substrings 'TAG', 'TAA', 'TGA'.

In this case I would solve it using two regular expressions. On implementing step 1-3 and one for the test in step 4:

```
 $sequence =~ /(ATG)([ACGT]{3})(TAG|TAA|TGA)/ and $2 !~ /TAG|TAA|TGA/;
```

Comment: That won't work, since you've included `[ACGT]` in the negative lookahead. See here: http://rubular.com/r/ISc65tpRez

Comment: No I didn't. The negative look-ahead is `(?!TAG|TAA|TGA)`

Comment: This achieves my exact goal. I want it to close the match on the first instance of (TAG|TAA|TGA). Thank you!

Comment: My initial solution was just a translation of you specification. I've added a simpler solution by rephrasing the specification a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should not have to have to exclude anything in the middle -- assuming you want the longest sequences to match. That's what Perl's `*` and `+` do already: they're greedy and match the longest possible sequence.

So in a simplified example if your input is `ABAACAAC` and you want to match everything starting with `B` ending with `C` with everything from `A`, `B` or `C` in the middle then `m/A[ABC]*C/` would already match `BAACAAC` and not just `BAAC`.

Generally you cannot use regular expressions in order to exclude specific things in the middle very well (although there are things like zero-width negative look-ahead/look-behind assertions).

Edit: And if you want to stop matching on the first occurrence of the "end pattern" then simply make `*` non-greedy by postfixing it with `?`. My example with non-greedyness: `m/A[ABC]*?C/`, although for this case I could also omit the `C` from the char class (because it's only a single letter in this simplified example).